# Read Euromillions Results url with Pandas read_csv ends up in MultiIndex

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

The national lottery in the UK publish their results at:
http://www.national-lottery.co.uk/player/euromillions/results/downloadResultsCSV.ftl

The data looks to be a well formed csv table and the first 3 rows appear as:

```
DrawDate,Ball 1,Ball 2,Ball 3,Ball 4,Ball 5,Lucky Star 1,Lucky Star 2,Raffle,DrawNumber
30-May-2014,27,41,24,45,5,7,6,HHR574198 ,698
27-May-2014,16,13,26,25,7,1,6,GHG710456 ,697
23-May-2014,31,3,47,8,34,11,9,FGX880402 ,696
```

When I try to load the csv directly from Pandas, I get a large Multi-Index and I was hoping to have a DataFrame? Any idea as to what arguments I need to focus on?

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://www.national-lottery.co.uk/player/euromillions/results/downloadResultsCSV.ftl'
test = pd.read_csv(url)
```

Comment: If you work out the secret of the lottery please share with SO....

Comment: Yes, I definitely will. I will upload my crumby code so that people can discuss the flawed merits of its approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a blank line for the first line, skip this and it loads fine:

```
In [6]:

import pandas as pd
url = 'http://www.national-lottery.co.uk/player/euromillions/results/downloadResultsCSV.ftl'
test = pd.read_csv(url, skiprows=1)
test
Out[6]:
       DrawDate  Ball 1  Ball 2  Ball 3  Ball 4  Ball 5  Lucky Star 1  \
0   30-May-2014      27      41      24      45       5             7   
1   27-May-2014      16      13      26      25       7             1   
2   23-May-2014      31       3      47       8      34            11   
.... # lines trimmed for brevity
48         650  
49         649  
50         648  

[51 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: @WoodyPride yes that is an alternative too, dunno which is more explicit in intention for me

Comment: as long as we get priority on the winnings I'll take either!

Comment: @WoodyPride I can tell you from personal experience that the lottery has been a huge personal disappointment, I mean why are people spending their winnings on cars, holidays, homes when they can startup a company similar to the one that Brewster founded in the film [Brewster's millions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svKq044qrYU) I mean that is seriously what I would do with the winnings

Comment: You and me man. We can put it all back in to finding the next set of numbers! Now that's a film